# How to rotate a picture using css and javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I want to simulate the rotating Moon on the upper-right corner of this [website](http://rlottering.com/)

If I already have the material "picture"

Give me some simple sample or tip then I will research it.
[image]

Comment: Look into CSS transformations.

Comment: It's already rotating? btw your portfolio looks good.

Comment: @AdrianEnriquez - That's not his site. He just wants to copy the effect.

Comment: wait @poc, i'll make a fiddle for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That site uses css transforms.Please check the demo I made.

### [Full Screen Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/q67qw/embedded/result/)

#### [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q67qw/)

To achive that ouput, Create animation keyframes first

**CSS**

```
@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to { 
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

then use it.

```
.moon{
-webkit-animation:rotate 420s infinite linear;
}
```

**NOTE:**
To make it work in other browsers, add css prefixes to your animations and usage like

```
 -ms
 -o
 -moz
```

Answer (score 1):

Google has a cool jquery plugin that will do the trick:

https://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/